# Making A Statistics Text File (Python)

Tags: python, text, file-io, tk-toolkit

I'm making a program that takes a name and certain input in the form of numbers and gives them a score i want this score to be saved in a text file and i want to be able to do it multiple times but when I write to the file it overwrites the last stat is there anyway to change this

Here is the function I'm using:

```
def calculate():
    try:
        a = float(enter1.get())
        b = float(enter2.get())
        c = float(enter3.get())
        d = float(enter4.get())
        e = float(enter5.get())
        f = float(enter6.get())
        result =(a+b+(c*2)+(d*2)+e-f)*2.5
        n = result
        w = "Score:"
        label7.config(text=str(result))
        myfile = open('Stats.txt','w')
        x = str(enter0.get())
        y =("(%s) %s" % (w, n))
        myfile.write(x)
        myfile.write(y)
        myfile.close()

    except ValueError:
        label7.config(text='Enter Numbers!',fg="white")
```

Comment: So you want the stats to be appended to the file?

Comment: yes! so that when i do a new name and new numbers it is written below the first stat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe change

```
myfile = open('Stats.txt','w')
```

into

```
myfile = open('Stats.txt','a') # append
```

Comment: Thanks i wasn't aware you could do that i fell dumb now !

Comment: @ChristianCareaga you dont have to. And if the answer solved your problem; it would be nice if you accepted this answer ;)